# How to access Angular 16 routes independently for standalone components

Tags: angular-routing, angular16

**Update**

The problem seems to be appearing with Angular 16 standalone components since there is no ngModule. To be specific, when the i run `ng build` the files are generated. Now i run the index.html file on vscode live server which opens the default route (http://127.0.0.1:5500/).

If i go to http://127.0.0.1:5500/search by typing in search bar. It doesn't work. or if i open this link in incognito tab. So what modification should i do to access it independently.

Reference code - [Code](https://github.com/suyashjawale/adaptive/tree/gh-pages)

**Old question**

I have ecom website where I'm serving two different ui versions for large and small devices.
I am able to do that using angular routing file. I can access **search** route by `localhost:4200/search` in development mode.

When i do `ng build` the **search** route is not accessible.

FYI -

1. Using angular 16 standalone components
2. Tried using pathMatch:'full'
3. Reason for having all components as children for MainComponent - MainComponent has header and footer common for all pages.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [];

export function getRoutes(): Routes {
  // if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
  //   return [
  //     {
  //       path: '',
  //       loadComponent: () => import('./components/small/home/home.component').then(mod => mod.HomeComponent),
  //     },
  //     {
  //       path: 'profile',
  //       loadComponent: () => import('./components/small/profile/profile.component').then(mod => mod.ProfileComponent),
  //     },
  //     {
  //       path: 'wishlist',
  //       loadComponent: () => import('./components/small/cart/cart.component').then(mod => mod.CartComponent),
  //     },
  //     {
  //       path: 'cart',
  //       loadComponent: () => import('./components/small/wishlist/wishlist.component').then(mod => mod.WishlistComponent),
  //     }
  //   ];
  // }
  // else {
    return [
      {
        path: '',
        loadComponent: () => import('./components/large/main/main.component').then(mod => mod.MainComponent),
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadComponent: () => import('./components/large/home/home.component').then(mod => mod.HomeComponent),
          },
          {
            path: 'search',
            loadComponent: () => import('./components/large/search/search.component').then(mod => mod.SearchComponent),
          },
          {
            path: 'profile',
            loadComponent: () => import('./components/large/profile/profile.component').then(mod => mod.ProfileComponent),
          },
          {
            path: 'wishlist',
            loadComponent: () => import('./components/large/wishlist/wishlist.component').then(mod => mod.WishlistComponent),
          },
          {
            path: 'cart',
            loadComponent: () => import('./components/large/cart/cart.component').then(mod => mod.CartComponent),
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  // }
}
```

Comment: The question has been resolved. I have imported withHashLocation to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Angular performs route matching sequentially. If the first route in a route in a routes array matches, it will stop looping through the array.
In your case it seems like angular found a match for `path: ''` and therefore doesn't continue to find matching routes (e.g. the `search` route).

In your case it first of all seems a little odd that you are splitting routes for different viewport sizes, but that's a whole different topic.

Another strange thing is that you always want to show the `MainComponent` as a wrapper, so you should probably exclude this component from routes configuration completely and use it as a wrapper for `router-outlet`, like:

```
<app-main-component>
  <router-outlet />
<app-main-component>
```

In this case you would only have one routing level (including `pathMatch: 'full'`):

```
return [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadComponent: () => import('./components/large/home/home.component').then(mod => mod.HomeComponent),
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    loadComponent: () => import('./components/large/search/search.component').then(mod => mod.SearchComponent),
  },
...
         
];
```

This would result in angular matching the HomeComponent only if `<HOST>` is matched. If you access `<HOST>/search`, the home route would not match and angular will try matching your search route.